# unable to set keymap for key Ctrl-;

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to set the global key for the C-; key by placing the below code in init.el file.

```
(global-set-key "\C-;" 'backward-kill-word)
```

But this gives the following error in the *Warning* buffer

```
error "Invalid modifier in string"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this,

```
 (global-set-key [(control ?\;)] 'backward-kill-word)
```

another way and I guess most easiest way of doing is with `kbd` function

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'backward-kill-word)
```

Comment: (global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'backward-kill-word)
 did not work, the first solution did worked. Thanks.